# ¿Cómo puedo detectar el nombre de usuario actual con Python en Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Básicamente lo que necesito es que este código (Ejemplo):

`buscar= r'C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local'`

En vez de que sea "usuario" la carpeta de user seleccionada, que busque la carpeta de la pc en la que está actualmente.

Por si no me expliqué bien:
Estoy usando ese código en Python, y dentro de la carpeta local busca un archivo ejecutable, lo que pasa es que si yo le paso el programa a otra persona mi código sigue buscando como si estuviera en mi pc, en vez de buscar en la actual cuenta de Users (Que sería en la pc de la otra persona).

No sé como hacer para:

`buscar= r'C:\Users\(que detecte el usuario actual)\AppData\Local'`

Comment: eso está en las variables de entorno del sistema, exactamente `username`

Comment: No, no es username, es [%USERPROFILE%](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)

Comment: @MauricioContreras `import os; print(os.getenv("USERNAME"))`

Comment: @Christian No, si el usuario tiene una configuración especial (digamos Windows instalado en otra unidad distinta de la C:) entonces aunque captures el valor de `username`, la ruta fallará. En cambio usando: `os.environ['USERPROFILE']` obtienes la ruta exacta. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería os que es para extraer información o hacer operaciones en el sistema operativo:

```
import os
print(os.path.expanduser('~')+'\\AppData\\Local')
```

os.path.expanduser('~') devuelve el directorio raíz del usuario actual.